# How to view and modify LDAP password configuration

Tags: centos, ldap

In my LDAP server, I want to know the value set for "passwordMinTokenLength" password policy configuration.

Is there a command line to see it (ldapsearch ?).

I try to update it with value 64 with command below but attribute is not found. So I don't know where is it .. ;

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin" -w  "pass" -H ldap:// -f /tmp/test.ldif

modifying entry "cn=xxxxx"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
```

LDIF File :

```
dn: cn=xxxxx
changetype: modify
# pas de controle
replace: passwordMinTokenLength
passwordMinTokenLength: 64
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you attempt to modify your item, you should check per ldapsearch, whether you can find your item.

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin" -w  "pass" -H ldap:// -b (your base) "(&(objectclass=LDAPSubEntry)(cn=xxxxxx))"
```

your base is a o= or.. ou=... and refers the (I think ou) sub tree / branch, on which  your policy set.

"AND" (objectclass=LDAPSubEntry) is crucial, otherwise you'll NEVER find yout item :)